# Changes color of 1st three rows only Data Tables

Tags: css, datatable

I am using datatables to sow data and i want to make different colors for top 3 rows 1st should be **green** 2nd **blue** and third row color should be **red**

My table structure is as

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#project').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
        { "orderable": false, "targets": [0,6,7] }
        ]
        });
        });
    });
</script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column dataTable no-footer" id="project" class="color">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th style="display:none"></th>
            <th>Sr</th>
            <th>Reg #</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($results as $index => $result)
    <tr>
        <td style="display:none"></td>
        <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
        <td class="sorting_1"> {{ $result->reg_no }} </td>
        <td>{{ $result->first_name }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to give style to first row as

```
.color td {
    background-color : green;
}
```

But not working please help to solve it

Thanks

Comment: .color is for complete table rite? What are you getting now?

Comment: Use css child selectors?

Comment: not now how to use @ayan

Comment: @GowthamShiva getting no effect

Comment: @recovery men, Something like `tr:nth-child(1)`

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers support CSS `nth-child` selectors. Backgroundcolours can be applied to the whole rows as such:

```
tbody>tr:nth-child(1) { /* etc */
    background-color: green;
}
```

Not all properties can be applied to rows. Sometimes you will need to apply them to the cells inside:

```
tbody>tr:nth-child(1) td {  /* or th */
    background-color: green;
}
```

If you are desperate, you can apply classes, but that is *not the best possible solution*. Classes should only be used to distinguish between elements which don’t follow a pattern.

Comment: thanks dear its working to me one thing more please i want to stop hover property for row 1 , 2 and 3 .. how can i achive

Comment: How did the `hover` property get there? Was is using CSS or jQuery. That will affect the answer.

Comment: its already there in data tables jquery files i want to disable only for top 3 rows

Comment: Look into what css is being applied by data tables and use the opposite in your css file under the hover selector.

Comment: **Note**:  On a paginated table this will color the first row on *every* page. I am not sure this is what OP really wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nth-child` selectors to achieve what you are trying to do. You can also learn about it here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

Try something like this:

```
tr:nth-child(1) {
 background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(2) {
 background-color: blue;
}
tr:nth-child(3) {
 background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(1):hover, tr:nth-child(2):hover, tr:nth-child(3):hover {
 /*
 Give whatever effect you want
 */
}
```